# What size tee fitting do I need for temporary tank?

Tags: fuel-line

I need to hook a temporary tank up to my carbs (for a carb sync).  I've got a temporary tank with single 1/4" ID rubber tube (barb on the tank measures 0.340" OD).  Of course, the motorcycle is metric, so has 7 mm ID fuel lines, and being a 4 cylinder has 2 rails to feed.

7mm is a bit bigger, but fittings that work well on 1/4" presumably would be "good enough" (when used with clamps) for this particular short term/controlled environment usage.  I'd feel fine about plugging the 7 mm ID hoses onto the tank's 0.340" OD barb if I didn't need the tee.

I've been trying to locate an appropriate 1/4" tee connector.  Local hardware/tractor/building supply stores only seem to carry larger stuff.  Pulling up brass tees on Grainger's site shows 1/4" tube size tees as having only 11/64" barbs, which would be way too small indeed if it's OD.  If I step up to 1/4" barb size though, the tube size balloons to 3/8" which makes no sense to me.  I'm very confused, none of this seems to match up to what I've got here.  Exactly what tee size should I be using to plug multiple 1/4" and 7mm ID rubber hoses together?

Comment: How flexible is the hose you are using? Is it soft/hard rubber?

Comment: Soft and quite flexible

Comment: Why not just go with the larger size fitting and stretch the hose over it ... should seal it well enough for what you need to do. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: That's the plan.  The problem is that I don't know what size to order to get that...  The local suppliers are all WAY too big, and the web site measurements don't make enough sense to me for me to be able to select something that I know is appropriate...

Comment: Check [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/Kent-Systems-TFN216-N02-Black-Fitting/dp/B012YMIAUS/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1499089454&sr=8-5&keywords=barbed+t+tube)?

Comment: Indeed I have.  They have a great many available, but it doesn't solve the root of the problem, which is that I don't know what listed size I need to order!  Does 1/4" mean for 1/4" hose?  Does 1/4" mean the barb is 1/4" (which would be too small)?

Comment: [Try this.](https://www.amazon.com/MettleAir-123-5-Union-Fitting-Intersection/dp/B007ZCQH6M/) This would be just a little bit larger than the 7mm (by .92mm). As long as your tubing is flexible, this should work for you. 1/4" tubing refers to the inside dimension. If it's 1/4" tube and it's flexible, you should be able to flex it over the barbs without issue. If it's flexible enough, it should fit up over the larger fitting.